# Is it possible to get touch events in a-frame (on mobile browser)?

Tags: javascript, mobile, aframe

I've tried adding an onclick event to my aframe entity, like so:

`<a-sphere id="sphere1" onclick="moveSphere()"
        position="0 1.25 -1" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>`

but it doesn't work on mobile.

alternatively, I've tried adding touch event listeners like so, but nothing happens:

`sphereElement.addEventListener('touchend', moveSphere);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

3D elements aren't like DOM elements, you can't register normal DOM events on them like touchend. You'd have to register them on the `canvas`

For that to work, you'd need a raycaster solution like https://jesstelford.github.io/aframe-click-drag-component/

```
<head>
  <script src="https://aframe.io/releases/0.3.0/aframe.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/aframe-click-drag-component"></script>
  <script>
    registerAframeClickDragComponent(window.AFRAME);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <a-scene>
    <a-sphere click-drag position="0 1.25 -5" radius="1.25" color="#EF2D5E"></a-sphere>
    <a-camera look-controls-enabled="false"></a-camera>
  </a-scene>
</body>
```

Comment: Oh really? I've added onclick and it has worked on a laptop. I will try this component on mobile then.  Thank you.

Comment: It might not have touch support, but the general idea is correct if you want to drag stuff around.

Comment: I have tried using this approach but I am getting an error that registerAframeClickDragComponent is not defined.